# I am trying to figure out why npn does not work here... what assumptions should be made?

Tags: operational-amplifier, npn

[image: circuit design]

So I tried the calculation of

1. ic = (15-10)/2k = 2.5mA -> ib = 25uA, ie = 2.525mA
2. Vce = 15 - 2k*(2.5mA+2.525mA) = 4.95V
3. As Vbe = 0.5V, Vb = 5.55V required
4. voltage drop by 10k resistor = 250mV -> Vop,output = 5.8V

and I'm stuck from here.

Should I say this model would not work because Vop,output should be zero?

Also, I tried some simulations and found out that flipping inputs work, but I don't get why that would not work in real life. (according to my instructor)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what "work" means in this context. The circuit you show has positive feedback so the op-amp output will rail (negative). That will likely cause the E-B junction of the transistor to break down in real life so the output voltage will be a volt or two below ground. The breakdown or may not be modeled in simulation. If it is not, the output voltage will be ~0V. Think about what a slight imbalance at the input does to the output. See if it will tend to compensate for the imbalance or if it will add more imbalance- if the latter, you've got positive feedback.

Flipping the inputs of the given circuit **may or may not** result in a stable output depending on the exact components. With the given resistor values and input voltage the gain is about -1 and there is a bit of phase shift so it may stabilize, likely with a somewhat degraded phase margin. If the gain of the transistor stage is too great or there is too much phase shift it may oscillate.

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish here, so I suppose any of the above may be considered "working". Even if the circuits mentioned above are stable they are something like a ~2.5mA constant-current source into a 2kΩ resistor, so the voltage would change with any loading on Vout. In other words, not a constant voltage output. There are applications for such a circuit, for example if the bottom 2kΩ resistor was replaced with a capacitor it would generate a linear slope over some range of voltage.

If you are just trying to buffer the output of the op-amp and get a constant voltage output for a range of loads on Vout to ground, an emitter follower with feedback from the emitter to inverting input would be the way to do it. The base resistor would limit the op-amp output current and a collector resistor would similarly limit the output current. You can divide the input voltage to 5V if that is what you want at the output. Note that this circuit will likely be stable as described, but much capacitive loading (way less than a typical IC bypass capacitor) will cause oscillation so it's not a practical voltage regulator without additional work.

Answer (score 6):

That configuration of resistors and transistor produces a "phase splitter", with a gain of about \$\frac{2k\Omega}{2k\Omega}=1\$:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsooRj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the signal at X shown in blue below, the collector (OUT1, orange) and emitter (OUT2, tan) of Q1 are copies of X, but 180° out of phase with each other, and somewhat offset:

[image]

It's important to consider the constraints on possible potentials of OUT1 and OUT:

[image]

OUT1 will never fall below about 7.5V, and OUT2 can't ever rise above that same level. This will have consequences for the op-amp. Also, notice that OUT1 starts to *rise* again when X exceeds 8V or so. This is a a reversal of the inverting behaviour, so we are not even able to state with certainty that OUT1 is an inversion of X!

It's also important to realise that it's possible to reverse-bias the base-emitter junction, if X goes significantly negative, and at some point that junction will break down and conduct. It would be foolish to power the op-amp from ±15V, since its output would then be able to invoke this condition.

It's clear that OUT1 (for \$V_X < 8V\$), where you are taking op-amp feedback from, is inverting with respect to the input X, a 180° phase shift. Then the op-amp's inverting input is applying another 180° shift, for combined shifts around the loop (from X all the way around, and back to X) of 360°, equivalent to no phase shift at all, 0°. That is, feedback is positive. It can be likened to steering a car in which turning the steering wheel to the left causes the car to turn right, and vice versa. Any error in direction will be *increased*, either to the left, and you crash into something on that side, or vice versa.

You might think, then, that you could just swap the non-inverting and inverting inputs of the op-amp:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmE28B.png)</sup>

This would indeed cause loop phase shift to become 180°, but only for \$V_X < 8V\$, which we noticed above. For \$V_X > 8V\$, loop phase shift would again become positive, and the system would likely oscillate.

The situation is very precarious, and will certainly oscillate for much of the range of possible values of \$V_{IN}\$.

You will have better luck closing the loop via OUT2, since the slope of its graph against \$V_X\$ is always positive, for a 0° phase shift, regardless of input potential. Therefore we feed back OUT2 to the op-amp's inverting input, to obtain a 180° phase shift, for negative feedback:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fb5vga.png)</sup>

As noted above, OUT2 cannot rise above 8V or so, but up to that limit we will indeed have the relationship \$V_{OUT2} = V_{IN}\$:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. The original circuit.*

What's happening here?

- Assume Q1 (the transistor) is off. V<sub>-</sub> is pulled to 15 V.
- Since V<sub>-</sub> > V<sub>+</sub> the op-amp output will be driven hard negative - as close to -15 V as it can get.
- Q1 will remain off. V<sub>out</sub> will be at 0 V.

[image]

*Figure 2. The modified circuit.*

What's happening here?

- Assume Q1 (the transistor) is off. V<sub>-</sub> is pulled to 0V.
- Since V<sub>-</sub> < V<sub>+</sub> the op-amp output will be driven positive.
- Q1 will start to turn on when the op-amp output gets above 0.5 V. V<sub>out</sub> will follow.
- The circuit will stabilise when V<sub>out</sub> = 10 V.

There's a problem! The two resistors form a voltage divider so (ignoring the base current) the maximum voltage you could get at the junction is 7.5 V. Therefore V<sub>-</sub> could never reach 10 V and the circuit will never be in control. This could be solved by removing the collector resistor.

Tip: always use component designators (R1, Q1, U1, etc.) on your schematics. It makes discussion much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

When current is not enough, Vc will be higher than 10V. The inverting-input>noninverting-input. The opamp will saturate to -15V. NPN is completely off. The circuit is wrong.

Comment: What about the case of flipped input?

Comment: The inverting input should be connected to the emitter of the transistor. This will provide the proper negative feedback to stabilize the circuit.